# How to debug high CPU usage on Java process, not caused by Java threads

Tags: java, linux, debugging, tomcat, cpu-usage

I have a Java application that runs on Tomcat on Linux. After running for several weeks, it starts taking close to 100% CPU (as displayed by 'top' command), but none of the Java threads takes more than 5% CPU; it's not kernel CPU either (that one is between 0.2-0.5%). So something else (native code? JVM itself?) is causing this high CPU usage. The problem can only be solved by restarting Tomcat.

So the question is: is there the way to find out what is causing this high CPU usage, if not Java threads? Is there a way to "look at" native libraries running inside Java process. Or what should be my debugging strategy in this case?

Versions: Linux 2.6 (CentOS), Apache Tomcat/6.0.33, JVM: Sun 1.6.0_29-b11. The application happens to be Forgerock OpenAM 10.0 (I am checking known issues on their end too, but so far didn't find the exact match, so looking for more generic suggestions)

Comment: how many threads are created at that time ?

Comment: What about memory usage ? Perhaps You have a lot of leaks, and garbage collector tries to keep up ?

Comment: there are 179 threads in that Java process

Comment: When you said "none of the Java threads takes more than 5% CPU" did you mean each one individually takes up no more than 5% CPU? Because if so, you could have 179 threads @ 5% each...which would easily be over 100% CPU...

Comment: @endriu_l: I'd expect that GC threads to be taking some significant CPU then? but they don't. Good idea though, I will check that.

Comment: @Scott Shipp: one thread utilizes 5% cpu, one more uses between 0.5 - 1.7%; all other threads are at 0%

Comment: You can download some trial versions of APM (Application performance management) tools to detect the issue easily. http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/top-five-apm-vendors-performance-results

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be long unanswered. Investigating cpu for a java process is based on analyzing the cpu consumption of each of the pthread of the jvm process. Here is a link to the post that explains this: http://www.learnings.today/investigating-cpu-usage-in-a-java-process/